# How to remove Location Box of Google Maps (top left)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I'm trying to list out all of the warehouse locations from Google Maps on my website by using Google Map's iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=118+Lamington+Rd.+–+Bateman+Student+Center,+Branchburg,+NJ+08876&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Currently, I'm stuck on how to remove the location box (top left) since I'm using this as an iframe. Is there a possible way that I can remove this part of the location box from iframe?

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <div style="background-color: white; margin: 10px; padding: 1px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 4px -1px; border-radius: 2px;">
        <div jstcache="0" style="">
            <div jstcache="117" class="place-card place-card-large">
                <div class="place-desc-large">
                    <div jstcache="36" class="place-name" jsan="7.place-name">Raritan Valley Community College</div>
                    <div jstcache="37" class="address" jsan="7.address">118 Lamington Rd, Branchburg, NJ 08876</div>
                </div>
                <div jstcache="38" class="navigate">
                    <div jsaction="placeCard.directions" class="navigate">
                        <a target="_blank" jstcache="52" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=40.609526,-74.688894&amp;z=16&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en-US&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=embed&amp;daddr=Raritan%20Valley%20Community%20College%20118%20Lamington%20Rd%20Branchburg%2C%20NJ%2008876@40.6095258,-74.6888942" class="navigate-link">
                            <div class="icon navigate-icon"></div>
                            <div jstcache="53" class="navigate-text">Directions</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tooltip-anchor">
                        <div class="tooltip-tip-outer"></div>
                        <div class="tooltip-tip-inner"></div>
                        <div class="tooltip-content">
                            <div jstcache="54">Get directions to this location on Google Maps.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div jstcache="39" class="navigate-separator"> </div>
                <div jstcache="40" class="star-entity">
                    <div jsaction="placeCard.star" class="star-button">
                        <div class="star-entity-icon-large">
                            <div jstcache="67" class="icon can-star-large" jsan="7.icon,7.can-star-large"> </div>
                            <div jstcache="68" class="icon logged-out-star" style="display:none"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div jstcache="69" class="star-entity-text hidden" jsan="7.star-entity-text,7.hidden,t-PmAZCbgKmDw">Saved</div>
                        <div jstcache="70" class="star-entity-text" jsan="7.star-entity-text,t-bbrD6GAQ-ds">Save</div>
                    </div>
                    <div jstcache="71" class="tooltip-anchor">
                        <div class="tooltip-tip-outer"></div>
                        <div class="tooltip-tip-inner"></div>
                        <div class="tooltip-content">
                            <div jstcache="72">Save this place onto your Google map.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div jstcache="41" class="review-box">
                    <div jstcache="42" class="review-number" jsan="7.review-number">4.0</div>
                    <div jstcache="43" jsinstance="0" class="icon rating-star rating-full-star" jsan="7.icon,7.rating-star,7.rating-full-star"></div>
                    <div jstcache="43" jsinstance="1" class="icon rating-star rating-full-star" jsan="7.icon,7.rating-star,7.rating-full-star"></div>
                    <div jstcache="43" jsinstance="2" class="icon rating-star rating-full-star" jsan="7.icon,7.rating-star,7.rating-full-star"></div>
                    <div jstcache="43" jsinstance="3" class="icon rating-star rating-full-star" jsan="7.icon,7.rating-star,7.rating-full-star"></div>
                    <div jstcache="43" jsinstance="*4" class="icon rating-star rating-empty-star" jsan="7.icon,7.rating-star,7.rating-empty-star"></div> <a target="_blank" jstcache="44" href="http://www.google.com/search?q=Raritan+Valley+Community+College,+118+Lamington+Rd,+Branchburg,+NJ+08876&amp;ludocid=1578495031502184362#lrd=0x89c3937dc5acab1f:0x15e7f0de30681faa,1" jsaction="mouseup:placeCard.reviews" class="review-box-link" jsan="7.review-box-link,8.href,0.target,22.jsaction">69 reviews</a> </div>
                <div jstcache="45" class="saved-from-source-link" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="bottom-actions">
                    <div class="google-maps-link"> <a target="_blank" jstcache="46" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=40.609526,-74.688894&amp;z=16&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en-US&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=embed&amp;cid=1578495031502184362" jsaction="mouseup:placeCard.largerMap">View larger map</a> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using css but it does not work:

```
div[style*="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"] {
    display: none;
}
```

I have also tried adding `iwloc=near` or `iwloc=A` on the URL, but it doesn't work still.

Comment: so you want to remove `view larger map` button ?

Comment: @NishargShah correct

Comment: Unclear + too broad + possibly against Google terms of service.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to remove the location card in the Maps Embed API is currently not available, however, you may file a Feature Request in the [Issue Tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=188814&template=788210) in order for the engineers to review the feasibility of the request. You may also try the workaround offered in this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/120395345). Hope this helps